# Running multiple topologies on stormcrawler with status index

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler

My use case:

I have a number of domains to crawl, with each having its own filter configuration. Each domain is now running as a topology.
I see that a few domains have crawled about 10M urls and have another 50M on the status queue.
The other topologies are sitting idle with just fetching the seed url. 
Each topology is has been given 2GB of RAM,10 threads per queue, max bucket is 50 and url per bucket is 100.

What could be the reason for the topologies to sit idle ..? I suspect the high number of urls in status queue in "discovered" state.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use as a backend? If it is ES, then you should be able to use Kibana to inspect the *status* index and see what happens to the seeds for those idle crawls. It could be that they are blocked by robots.txt and can't progress any further.

I'd use a single status index and a single topology for all the domains - which would be easier to manage and monitor. The URL filtering can be easily set for each seed e.g. by defining a separate URL filter file per domain within the filter's configuration or even all within the same URL filter file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, In my case I have about 300 domains and a group of subdomains under it.

Hence using multiple topology makes it easier, as each domain has its own limitation on crawl speed.